# JupyterLab Terminal: Packages not recognized

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, jupyter-lab, iterm2

Why does Terminal in JupyterLab (JL) not recognize certain packages?  For instance, I have the following simple script called `foo.py` that simply imports pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
```

And when I try to execute at the Terminal command line in JL, I get the following:

```
$ python foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I tried the following four steps but was still unable to execute `foo.py` in JupyterLab Terminal:

1. Executed `foo.py` in iTerm2 (outside of JL) in the same environment.  No problem.
2. Executed `foo.py` in iPython (from JL Terminal) in the same environment. No problem.
3. Executed `$conda list` (from JL Terminal) and confirmed existence of Pandas.
4. Executed `conda install pandas` (from JL Terminal). Still unable to run `foo.py` after reinstalling.

So my two questions are:

1. Big picture, how can I ensure environment consistency between iTerm2 and JupyterLab Terminal?
2. Immediate concern, how can I rectify the above problem and utilize scripts that rely on Pandas from JupyterLab Terminal?

Comment: Have you activated the conda environment in the terminal?

Comment: @krassowski Yes I have.